# API keys and require in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, rails-api

New to Rails here and have not used an API before. I wanted to incorporate this into my app https://github.com/codeforamerica/congress where would I put the code found under set up? I've been reading it should go in an environment file, or should I put this in an initializer? I've seen a lot of different options and was just wondering if anyone could help explain using API's in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a file in the initializers folder, as for the api key, you could place it there too, but if it should be secret then you could replace it with an environment variable

```
require 'congress'
Congress.key = EVN['ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_KEY']
```

Then add the environment variable in `~/.profile` or something

Comment: This may be a lot to ask but what's the difference between putting something in an initializer file or in an environments file? Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: there's a difference between environment files and the linux environment variables, environment files `/config/environment` are where the settings for each environment are saved, but what we're talking about here are the linux environment variables, we use those when you want to keep certain things away from the version control, like database passwords, or smtp passwords, etc